# Trying to call an activity, but having troubles with onClick

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick

im trying to run this simple code (im a beginner :).

trying to run this. the // text is usually what i use for buttons. however, i saw this switch technique that i wanted to try, it seemed more efficient. however, i get errors related to the onClick (something about the ( ) and that 'void is an invalid type'). i have no idea what can cause this. just wanna access the buttons. can anyone please tell me why?

Thanks!

```
    package com.experiment.fewops;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class FewOptions extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        final Button sexy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSexy);
        final Button text = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonText);

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //        sexy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //          
    //          @Override
    //          public void onClick(View v) {
    //              Intent intent = new Intent(this, SexyPage.class);
    //              startActivity(intent);
    //          }
    //      });

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonSexy:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SexyPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }

    };


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually 2 problems here: 
First, as @Saiesh said, if you want to implement the click listener at the class level, you need to change your class declaration to implment OnClickListener. So your declaration will look like

```
public class FewOptions extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

The second problem (and the reason you're getting the error about void being a bad type) is that you're declaring the onClick method in the body of your onCreate method. move the declaration of the onClick method outside the closing brace (`}`) of the onCreate method and that error should go away.

One more note: after you make the 2 fixes above, don't forget to add your class as the click listener for the button:

```
 sexy.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass right context

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FewOptions.this,SexyPage.class);
FewOptions.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution is that to use this onClick() method your class needs to implement the onClickListener interface . Thus your class heading should be something like this

```
public class FewOptions extends Activity implements onClickListener
{
       //Eclipse will automatically ask you to override the onClick() method
}
```

So thats the solution :)